# What is the best practice?

Tags: java, oop, javabeans

What is the best coding standard for Java for a bean variable:

**1. Should I use primitive data type?

2. Should I use wrapper type?**

Or both are same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends. Both exist for a good reason.

Primitives should be preferred as much as possible. They cost less, and are non-nullable, which avoids quite a lot of potential bugs.

A wrapper can be used to represent a nullable value (for example, in JPA, to represent a nullable column value in a database, or in JAXB, to represent an optional element or attribute of an XML element).

Answer (score 5):

That depends. 
For example, your bean may be populated with information from database. 
Columns may hold nullable data, according to the definition. 
In this case , you will consider using the non-primitie type - i.e Integer. 
However, you may want to work with primitive types + operations, so auto-boxing/unboxing will take place (i.e - automatically converting from Integer and to integer, depending on your code) which might hurt performance a bit. 
To conclude,
Try to use primitive where possible, use non-primitive for cases you might need to hold a Null value.

Answer (score 3):

Use primitives where you can, but don't use them when you need to store null values

examples:

```
Boolean isObject;
boolean isPrimitive;

int xPrimitive;
Integer xObject;
```

If you store these values, you'd find that they're not equal.

```
// isObject == null
// isPrimitive == false

// xPrimitive == 0
// xObject == null
```

So best practice is whatever makes sense for your application.  Optimizing, you'd want to use primitives over objects for less memory overhead - but only if it doesn't conflict with your business and logic requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Generally best to use primitives rather than wrappers. The wrappers are great for methods such as

```
Integer.toString(myInt);
```

This method is from a wrapper class but `myInt` is a primitive. In general use, primitives will do all that you need

Answer (score 1):

I used Primitive type.

For example:

```
private int i;
private boolean b;

public int getI()
{
}

public void setI(int i)
{
    this.i = i;
}

public boolean getB()
{
}

public void setB(boolean b)
{
    this.b = b;
}
```

and use the setters and getters. Thanks

Comment: A String is not a primitive type.

Comment: A better answer would be "use primitive types *unless you **need** to be able to represent "no value" as well"*.

Comment: The convention for `boolean` properties is to use `is` instead of `get`, so it should be `public boolean isB() {`.

Comment: Getters and setters shouldn't be added unless there is a good reason. Otherwise, it would tend to become an anemic model and so breaks encapsulation since "behaviour" would be coded outside the bean. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model